# Is there a git-like Google Drive client for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, git, google-drive

<sup><sub>(Ported from SuperUser on the advice of @kenorb)</sub></sup>

I'm an avid user of Google Drive to sync files between my laptop, smartphone, and work computer.  It makes my life much simpler, as I can easily archive, share, and store files (this is not meant as an advertisement for Drive, I promise).

However, I tend to split my time between Windows at home and Ubuntu at work.  Furthermore, I've recently divided my laptop's hard drive into several partitions so that I can dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu:

```
--> Windows partition
--> Ubuntu partition
--> Data partition (seen by both Windows and Ubuntu)
```

I'm worried about installing the Windows Google Drive client in the data partition, as I worry it might create inconsistencies in the data that lead to syncing problems if I edit a file in Ubuntu and switch back to Windows.

I know that for Linux, [this](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) application, originally written by a Google developer, provides git-like push and pull functionality for Google Drive.

So several questions:

(1) Are my fears about data inconsistencies founded?

(2) If so, is there a similar option for Windows (that provides the git-like push and pull functionality for Google Drive)?

(3) And finally, would this address those data inconsistencies in the first place?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>FWIW, I'm willing to DTFE if necessary when it comes to question 3 - I just would like some guidance before I mess up my Drive :)</sub></sup>

Comment: I'd go with installing drive on BOTH the Windows and Ubuntu partitions - that is, two separate copies of your drive items. That way, each copy will obey normal data consistency rules and you shouldn't run into any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I would say use git itself - if you have your main local repository on the data drive and clone it onto your Windows and Linux partitions you can pull from & push to that repository from either OS and use the solution that you have already identified to sync to Drive, or git itself to sync to one of a pile of git hosts available online.

### Update

There are a number of articles on-line about repository corruptions when using Drive/Dropbox/etc. so please look at a proper git server account, e.g. [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) *unlimited public & private repos shareable with up to 5 others in free plan*, [GitHub](https://github.com/) *no private repos in free*, one of many others.

Answer (score 0):

There is [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive). It has fewer features than the drive client you use on linux, but it works on windows and supports upload,download and sharing.

If you are used to "syncing" your files manually, why change your habits?